# JAXB unmarshal map with object that contains yet another map

Tags: jaxb, hashmap

I have already use JAXB successfully to unmarshal certain xml file but I have another case that is more complex. Basically my xml file looks like these:

```
<BCLCurrenciesInflation>
<currenciesInflation>
    <currency>
        <curencyName>Yen</curencyName>
        <countryName>Japan</countryName>
        <issuingDate>1900-01-01</issuingDate>
        <expirationDate></expirationDate>
        <inflation>
            <year>1900</year>
            <percentage>16</percentage>
        </inflation>
        <inflation>
            <year>1901</year>
            <percentage>17</percentage>
        </inflation>
    </currency>
    <currency>
        <curencyName>Dolar</curencyName>
        <countryName>USA</countryName>
        <issuingDate>1900-01-01</issuingDate>
        <expirationDate></expirationDate>
        <inflation>
            <year>1902</year>
            <percentage>18</percentage>
        </inflation>
        <inflation>
            <year>1903</year>
            <percentage>19</percentage>
        </inflation>
    </currency>
</currenciesInflation>
```

so is basically a `HashMap<String,BCLCurrency>` and BCLCurrency looks like this:

```
public class BCLCurrency
{
@XmlElement(name = "currencyName")
public String name;

@XmlElement(name = "countryName")
public String country;

@XmlElement(name = "issuingDate")
public String issuingDate;

@XmlElement(name = "expirationDate")
public String expirationDate;

@XmlElement(name = "inflation")
public Map<String,float> inflationMap;
}
```

I was thinking about having two adapters, the second will be called from the first adapter but I don't feel comfortable with that solution.

Any ideas of how to pull this off?

PD: Funny story I cannot say hello at the beginning of the post, the system keeps suppressing it!

Comment: OK. I think I made it. I will post back shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create/use a generic adaptor for map < K,V > instead of creating two adaptors.